# UIButton with autolayout doesn't appear in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I updated `Xcode` from 7.1.1 to 8 just before and found that `UIButton` is not appearing. Before updating Xcode it worked well.
I am using `autolayout` and tried to make round button.

**My Code**

```
btn.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
btn.layer.cornerRadius = btn.frame.size.height/2;
```

I tried this code, but not working for me

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Even I confirmed the button is visible in the Debug View Hierarchy.

Below I attached debug view hierarchy.

[UIButton appears in Debug View Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9SnF.png)

Comment: Did you use width & height constraints for button?

Comment: Click your button, goto identity inspector, scroll down in the last and check whether there is constraint for some other sizeclass present or not. If yes then check the option "installed".

Comment: yes,  the button has width and height constraints.

Comment: I just solved the issue, posted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this issue.

I moved those code from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear and it works fine.

```
btn.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
btn.layer.cornerRadius = btn.frame.size.height/2;
```